# Inner spacing between images?

Tags: css

I wanted to create a gallery with thumbnails, however I ran into an issue. If I want to space out the thumbs, I should do something like `margin-right: 15px;`, however that would create space for the furthest-right image. How would I go about creating those spaces without having them at the edge of a template?

Example:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: do you need them evenly spaced?

Comment: It would look more aesthetically pleasant

Comment: then you can't use `:last-child` because it would push the last element further away than the others' spacing.

Comment: edit: can't *solely rely on* `:last-child`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is negative margins on the container element:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYhum/

```
.container {
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}

.container .image {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    /* either floated or set to inline-block */
}
```

If your container is responsive (ie. you don't know how wide it will be), flexbox is worth a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/LYhum/4/ (has fallback for browsers without flexbox support)

```
.container {
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -moz-justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .image {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `<li>` here, but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
ul.thumbs li {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
ul.thumbs li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

use the `:last-child` pseudo-selector. (Just keep in mind some of the [quirks](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html))

Comment: Not me! Thanks for your answer Brad

Comment: Not implying it was, but I've noticed an increase of down-votes lately without a comment explanation/rationalization. Kind of disappointing.

Comment: Downvote because it's wrong?  If the elements wrap around so that they take up multiple lines, then only the very last element in the very last row of the set will have the `margin-right: 0`.  That won't help the last element that appears in any other line.

Comment: I downvoted because this will only push the last element to the right, it doesn't follow the picture's idea of evenly spacing squares. you'll notice in the second example the boxes are wider to compensate for the difference.

Comment: @cimmanon: I wasn't aware of how many children the list would have. The OP only showed one line and assumed [for right or wrong] that they knew the items should be Npx wide with Mpx spacing (exempt from last item. But you're correct, if they spanned multiple lines this would not be effective.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do some math if you want them evenly spaced, edge to edge.

subtract the width of the squares with the margin you'd like so that there is no gap.

```
(width of container) - ((# of squares)*(width of squares))
divided by (# of squares - 1)) == margin required for even spacing
```

for example:

if container width is 300px, and square with is 30px, make margin-right == 37.5px (150px divided by 4 (4 spaces between them) )... *THEN use something like the :last-child trick to correct the last square. (or just hard code the 0 margin on the last square)* Without doing the proper math, the last square will have a different spacing than the other 4 squares.

```
| ------------------------   300px    ------------------| == the container
|square1-----square2-----square3-----square4-----square5|
|   ^     ^    ^      ^    ^      ^     ^      ^    ^
|  30   37.5   30    37.5  30   37.5   30    37.5  30   | == 300px

* not to scale :)


.square {
    width:30px;
    margin-right:37.5px;
}
#square5 {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

**edit** this will all depend on the width of the container...if it is not hard-coded in pixels, (i.e. it is %), then i'd suggest doing the same sort of math, but using %width and %margin instead.